# Missed Outlook meeting notifications, how to make them more obvious?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-office-2013

I use Outlook 2013 at work to remind me of meetings and appointments.  However, when the reminder pops up, all that happens is the Outlook icon in the system tray glows orange:

[image]

It doesn't blink or anything, just changes colors.  About 50% of the time I miss this.  Is there anything I can do to make these alerts more obvious?  Some sort of balloon popup?  Every time Windows needs to download a security patch, it won't let me hear the end of it; but it decides to be super timid about telling me I have an important phone call in five minutes.  In *Outlook Options->Advanced*, I did see a *Show Reminders* checkbox:

[image]

And there *is* a reminder, I just have to click on the glowly orangeness to actually see it.

Plug-ins or third party add-ons would also be acceptable.  Thanks!

**Update:**

I upgraded to Office 2016 Pro, and the behavior is still the same.  Keeping Outlook non-minimized also doesn't help, since the reminders won't automatically pop up on top of other windows.  I don't see any new settings related to popups or notifications in this version either.

Comment: This isn't normal behavior.  Normal behavior is to provide a notification window, even if outlook is minimized, are you on a domain by chance?  You should get a notification bubble for all emails does that happen?

Comment: @Ramhound - I am on a domain, yes.  And yea, I think this only repros when Outlook itself is minimized.  I prefer to keep it minimized if possible.

Comment: I am on a domain myself.  I also have Office 2016 linked to a personal Exchange account.  In both cases the default setting is a notification window to remind me about events that are happening and to display a [notification bubble](http://www.technipages.com/enabledisable-outlook-mail-notification-box) when I receive an email.  Windows 10 in both cases.

Comment: I can upgrade to a newer version of Office, since we have an MSDN subscription here.  Was just wondering if there was a way to get Outlook 2013 working the way I'd expect.

Comment: @Ramhound - Downloading Office 2016 now :)

Comment: Its likely just a setting.  You could delete the outlook profile, but backup your data files, to see if that helps.  [Additional Help](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/outlook-2010-calendar-reminders-are-not-popping-up/0f361a54-4d54-4718-a3eb-7755448c457b?db=5&auth=1).  My domain account is Office 2010, my point was, the default behavior is suppose to work with it minimized.  This behavior has not changed since at least Outlook 2007, can't say anything about versions before that, work has only provided 2007+

Comment: I'm on Outlook 2013 and I get the Meeting notification window.

Comment: @surfasb - Even when Outlook is minimized?  What OS are you on?

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying out SureAlerts, an expensive add-on that does what I want: pops the reminder in front. I also added a longer alarm sound within Outlook itself.

Comment: Did you mean to leave this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to fix in Outlook 365.

1. In Outlook go to File > Options > Advanced.
2. Under the "Reminders" section, click the checkbox "Show reminders on top of other windows".
3. Click OK to save the change.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found the Advanced settings not to work on all installations of windows and outlook. One work around that I have used is to change the sound file for "Play Reminder Sound:" in the dialog that you showed to something that lasts several seconds. I admit that this also has drawbacks since it can also be annoying, but it is harder to ignore.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).